# magento 2.4 Cache RedirectDataCacheSerializer InvalidArgumentException: Couldn't retrieve data from cache

Tags: cache, magento2.4.6

After upgrading to MAG 2.4.6-p3 I am getting a cache error. Would anyone have any suggestions?

Here is my log, I think its being generated when someone tries to order. I figure it must be a store ID  problem but am not sure where to start to track this down.

Thank you for any help or suggestions you can offer. Have a great day everyone.

[2024-03-02T04:46:12.070724+00:00] main.ERROR: InvalidArgumentException: Couldn't retrieve data from cache. in vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreSwitcher/RedirectDataCacheSerializer.php:85
Stack trace:
#0 vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreSwitcher/HashProcessor.php(120): Magento\Store\Model\StoreSwitcher\RedirectDataCacheSerializer->unserialize('Kcwz3yxxiQ9v3JY...')
#1 vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreSwitcher.php(53): Magento\Store\Model\StoreSwitcher\HashProcessor->switch(Object(Magento\Store\Model\Store\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Store\Model\Store\Interceptor), 'https://store.q...')
#2 vendor/magento/module-store/Controller/Store/SwitchAction.php(126): Magento\Store\Model\StoreSwitcher->switch(Object(Magento\Store\Model\Store\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Store\Model\Store\Interceptor), 'https://store.q...')
#3 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Store\Controller\Store\SwitchAction->execute()
#4 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Store\Controller\Store\SwitchAction\Interceptor->___callParent('execute', Array)
#5 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Store\Controller\Store\SwitchAction\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}()
#6 generated/code/Magento/Store/Controller/Store/SwitchAction/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Store\Controller\Store\SwitchAction\Interceptor->___callPlugins('execute', Array, Array)
#7 vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(111): Magento\Store\Controller\Store\SwitchAction\Interceptor->execute()
#8 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#9 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Store\Controller\Store\SwitchAction\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#10 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Store\Controller\Store\SwitchAction\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#11 generated/code/Magento/Store/Controller/Store/SwitchAction/Interceptor.php(32): Magento\Store\Controller\Store\SwitchAction\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#12 vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(245): Magento\Store\Controller\Store\SwitchAction\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#13 vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(212): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->getActionResponse(Object(Magento\Store\Controller\Store\SwitchAction\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#14 vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(147): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), Object(Magento\Store\Controller\Store\SwitchAction\Interceptor))
#15 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#16 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#17 vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(99): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#18 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#19 vendor/ulmod/module-spam-blocker/Plugin/FormPostPredispatch.php(151): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#20 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Ulmod\SpamBlocker\Plugin\FormPostPredispatch->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#21 vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(71): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#22 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#23 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#24 generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)
#25 vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(116): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#26 vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(264): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#27 pub/index.php(30): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#28 {main} {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Couldn't retrieve data from cache. at vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreSwitcher/RedirectDataCacheSerializer.php:85)"} []